# Binary search stuck infinite loop?

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, binary-search

I created this binary search but it seems to get stuck in a loop each time. All it's checking is a vector. I'm stuck as to what I need to change I've tried so many different things.

[1,2,4,6] if I search for 4 is never is found it keeps hitting the lower = mid + 1.

```
bool SortSearch::binarySearcher(int size, int val)
{
    int lower = 0, upper = size - 1, mid;

    while (lower < upper)
    {
        mid = (lower + (upper-lower))/2;
        if (students[mid].getID() > val)
            upper = mid - 1;
        else if (students[mid].getID() < val)
            lower = mid + 1;
        else if (students[mid].getID() == val)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use the debugger (or print statements) to track the flow of your program.

Comment: I was using the debugger which is why I knew it was looping at the spot with that value. That worked I didn't notice I had the extra () which was the cause of the issue. Thanks I also added the homework tag since they wanted us to implement it ourselves.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe:

```
mid = (lower + (upper-lower))/2;
```

should be:

```
mid = lower + (upper-lower)/2;
```

I'd probably add:

```
assert(lower <= mid && mid <= upper);
```

Also, the:

```
return false;
```

should be after the loop.  Once you've checked `<`, and `>`, the only possible result left is `==` (with ints), so that final `else` clause will never hit.  (If you were using a floating point type for the index, then you can get some weird situations with NaNs, infinities, and maybe negative zeroes.)

Turn up the warning level on your compiler.  It should have warned you about the unreachable code and the path without a return.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
mid = (lower + (upper-lower))/2;
```

Should probably be:

```
mid = lower + (upper-lower) / 2;
```

Or simply the average:

```
mid = (upper + lower) / 2;
```

Comment: The "simple average" is faster, but has a potential problem, that if the array is in the higher half of the virtual memory range, it could overflow, and that will either give the wrong answer or exhibit undefined behavior, depending on if pointers are signed or not.

Comment: It could, but note that these are indexes. If the element size is bigger than one byte then that never overflows provided `size_t` is used for indexes.

Comment: @MooingDuck -- 'upper' and 'lower' are integers, not pointers.  AFAIK, it is illegal to add two pointer values.

Comment: Even if they aren't pointers (you're right, they're obviously not), the point stands, the "simple" average still errors in more cases than the OP's code.

Answer (score 2):

It might be illuminating to print the values of `lower`, `upper`, and `mid` on each iteration. Consider what happens when `lower` and `upper` only differ by 1 - then `mid` will be calculated to be equal to `lower`, which means on the next iteration that `lower` and `upper` will be identical to the previous iteration, leading to an infinite loop condition.

Comment: I thought I'm checking for that with the lower < upper in the while loop instead of it being lower <= upper?

Comment: You're right - I missed that you're assigning `mid +/- 1` to the appropriate bound to prepare for the next iteration...